# How to hide the icon in TimePickerDialog?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timepickerdialog

Is it possible to hide the keyboard icon in timepicker dialog?

> [image]

Comment: Post your code for TimePickerDialog

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790910/how-to-turn-off-keyboard-icon-at-timepicker